# RecyclerViewClickListener onClick not working in fragment when several fragments included in an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

This one is a bit hard to explain and demonstrate. I will try my best.
I have two fragments ItemListFragment and ItemViewFragment : a fragment with a recycleview and listing inside the recycleview  and a fragment displaying a single item respectively.

In the ItemListFragment, there is RecyclerViewClickListener to handle clicks on items of the list.
The implementation is as followed:

```
public class ItemListFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnFragmentListClickListener onClickListener = null;

    public interface OnFragmentListClickListener {
        void OnFragmentListClick(ItemModel Item);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        class RecyclerViewClickListenerImpl implements RecyclerViewClickListener {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                if (onClickListener != null) {
                    onClickListener.OnFragmentListClick(adapter.getItem(position));
                }
        }

        adapter = new ItemListAdapter(getActivity(), ItemModelList, new RecyclerViewClickListenerImpl());
        mRecyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        .
        .
        .
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onAttach", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentListClickListener) {
            onClickListener = (OnFragmentListClickListener) context;
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The list contains thumbnail (loaded with Glide) and a text for each time.

When I add this fragment in my activity implementing the ItemListFragment.OnFragmentListClickListener interface, everything works fine using the code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements ItemListFragment.OnFragmentListClickListener {
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ItemListFragment fragment_list = ItemListFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment_list);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void OnFragmentListClick(CameraModel camera) {
        // handle the list click
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Things get weird when I try to add a second fragment (ItemViewFragment) in my activity as followed:

When there is a second fragment, the RecyclerViewClickListener's onClick on the ItemListFragment is not called anymore:

```
class RecyclerViewClickListenerImpl implements RecyclerViewClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, int position) {
        if (onClickListener != null) {
            onClickListener.OnFragmentListClick(adapter.getItem(position));
        }
}
```

Also, certain thmbnails in the ItemListFragment stopped working when a second fragment has been added in the activity.

This is a weird one... I tried using fragmentTransaction.add instead of fragmentTransaction.add also and all kind of combinations...

Comment: I knew this one would be tricky lol :)

Comment: haha knew this one would have no answers... too complex
Will find a solution by myself

Answer (score 0):

You want put your onClick in item of recycle view. You should do every thing of item (like: load image, make event for view,... ) in ViewHolder class. Beacause that's easier to view source code in your activity or fragment. You can references my ViewHolder class with this [link](https://github.com/l0ngse3/MovieHub---COP/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/myapplication/Ui/Adapter/Admin/ManageFilmCommentAdapter.java). It will help you.

Comment: from what I have read, this is actually not the good approach ... handling of the click event should not be done in the viewHolder but in the fragment and I assume it is even better to do it in the activity (this is what I have done)